# Missing a framework for arcore

Tags: c#, xcode, unity-game-engine

Did anyone encounter this before? It said missing ARcore base but I have already enabled This in the XR management
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Xcode project with the *.xcworkspace file and not with the *.xcodeproj file.

[image]